# jQuery Regular Expression does not work properly

Tags: jquery, regex, testing

I am trying to increase security on Email/Password input fields using regular expressions but I am having bad time because I cannot find what I am doing wrong. So basically I'm creating 2 variables where I'm storing my Regex pattern and after that I want to use jquery to catch the submit button and when .on('click') if there is added correct information by users to redirect them to next page for example. I have been testing my regular expression and they are matching my requirements -  they are returning true for Email/Password after testing with .test().
Here is my code example of what I am trying to build:

```
  var userValidation = /^[\w-]+@[\w-]+\.[A-Za-z_-]{2,4}$/;
  var passValidation = /((?=.*d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).{8,15})/gm;
  console.log(userValidation.test('test@gmail.com')); // testing
  console.log(passValidation.test('12345678Kksad')); // testing
```

Actual code which I am trying to run

```
$('.button').on('click', function(){
    if ($('#user') === userValidation && $('#pass') === passValidation){
        window.location.replace("http://stackoverflow.com");
    }else{
        console.log('not working properly');
    }
})
```

Every time when I enter email and password in both input fields it returning the else statement does not matter if the information is correct or not according my regular expressions.

Comment: You have several issues in the password validation regex: try `var passValidation = /^(?=\D*\d)(?=[^a-z]*[a-z])(?=[^A-Z]*[A-Z]).{8,15}$/;`. It must be anchored with `^`/`$` obligatorily.

Answer (score 3):

There is several issue in your code.

Here is a complete example.

**CSS** :

```html
<form id="form" action="/validate" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="email"/>
    <input type="password" name="password">
    <button type="submit" >Submit</button>
</form>
```

**JS** :

```js
var emailRegex = /^[\w-]+@[\w-]+\.[A-Za-z_-]{2,4}$/;
var passRegex = /^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])[\da-zA-Z]{8,}$/;

$('#form').submit(function(event) {
    event.prevendDefault();
    // get email and password value
    var email = $(this).find('input[name=email]').val();
    var password = $(this).find('input[name=password]').val();
    // validate email and password 
    if (emailRegex.test(email) && passRegex.test(password)){
        window.location.replace("http://stackoverflow.com");
    } else {
        console.log('not working properly');
    }
});
```

Comment: the pattern of the `passValidation` object is wrong.

Comment: Five things! 1) the pattern is not anchored at the beginning (`^`), consequence, it is tested at each position of the string until it eventually succeeds (you only need that the pattern succeeds at position 0). 2) the pattern is not anchored at the end (`$`), so the password can be longer than 15 characters. (same thing if the beginning anchor is missing) 3) the capture group is useless. 4) the g (you only need one successful match) and m (why do you want to change the meaning of anchors `^` and `$`?) modifiers are useless too. 5) `(?=.*d)` => `(?=.*\d)`

Comment: Note too that the `String.prototype.match` isn't appropriate for a validation (you don't care of an array with matched results), `RegExp.prototype.test` is better fitted for this task.

Comment: yes, you are right. The password and email regex can be greatly improved but, It's not the goal of the question. His code wasn't working not because its regex wasn't good. That's why I didn't focused my answer on regex. It's an other question "how to improve my password regex" for code review site. I agree with you for `match` and `test` -> updated :)

Comment: It isn't only an improvement, the pattern is false.

Comment: @LouisBarranqueiro, Please do not recommend broken questions for Code Review, as those will be shut down almost immediately.

Comment: I updated my answer with a better password regex. Thank you @CasimiretHippolyte

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you could make a minor change to your existing event handler function to match the input field values with your regular expressions;

```
$('.button').on("click", function () {
  if ($('#user').val().match(userValidation) && $('#pass').val().match(passValidation)) {
      window.location.replace("http://stackoverflow.com");
  } else {
      console.log('not working properly');
  }
});
```